# Android emulator cannot be started from windows console

Tags: android, console, emulation

I'm trying to run my android emulator on windows console but I get this error:

```
emulator: ERROR: Your system directory is missing the 'kernel-qemu' image file.
Please specify one with the '-kernel <filepath>' option
```

**how can I fix this?**. thanks for tour time.

**----- UPDATE -----**

I finally can fix this error. At fisrt, I planned to install android SDK offline rather than using SDK Manager. So I followed up [this instruction](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html) and downloaded the components I need. Everything is correctly except that when I extract the platform using IZArc the file kernel-qemu which located in */platform/images/* **is not extracted**. But when I manually choose the file from IZArc and drag it to any folder it's extracted. Maybe this is about IZArc configuration but this error cost me for almost a week!

Answer (score 0):

do you have your kernel image file under

> < android >/tools/lib/images/

directory?

but i think your problem is your sintaxis to run the emulator

> ./emulator -kernel kernel-qemu -system
>   system.img -ramdisk ramdisk.img
>   -initdata userdata.img -partition-size 512

Comment: thanks for your advice. I finally know where the spine is. :)